# Bootstrap modal line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to use a Bootstrap modal with a lot of inputs but I have an issue, my modal have `modal-body` inside that div I create my form, `col-md-12, inputs, labels, more inputs, etc` then I have `modal-footer` with buttons (close and submit), the problem here is that `modal-body` creates a line like a `<hr>` tag and `modal-footer` too, is supposed that my form controls be between that lines, here is a pic of my problem:

[image: Problem]

And here is the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Editar Alerta</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">                    
            <label class="control-label">ID:</label>
            <input id="ID" name="ID" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" />                  
          </div>                  
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Revision:</label>
            <input id="revision" name="revision" type="text" class="form-control" />  
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Proposito:</label>
            <select class="form-control required" id="purpose" name="purpose"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** With window resized works fine, the problem happen with full width, like the width from codepen.io, to see this  [Check this code example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jraPqb) [or this fiddle and resize window](https://jsfiddle.net/1ctq8vs4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first `col-md-12` in the `modal-body` to a `row` class, that will make the contents remain inside the modal body